# Existence orientation of finite simple graph with unique sink

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I consider a finite simple connected graph without loops and I am wondering whether there is always an orientation which has a unique sink, I.e., a vertex only with in-edges.

I proceeded algorthmically by picking first any vertex and declaring any incident edge as an in-edge. I then pick any source of these edges and declare the remaining edges as in-edges for these vertices. This leads to a problem, if there is a triangle but in this case choosing arbitrarily a direction of the third edge works out to not creating additional sinks. I continue with all sources of the new in-edges which have not already been considered before and continue.

I tried this on $K_{5,5}$, $K_{10}$, $J(5,2)$ and a couple of trees (for which it works trivially). Does the algorithm always work or is there even a rigorous result on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way of doing this.

1. Pick any vertex $v$ that you want to be the unique sink vertex.
2. Letting $i$ be a nonnegative integer, let $N^i_G(v)$ be the set of vertices $w$ where (a) there is a path $P_{vw}$ in $G$ from $v$ to $w$ where $P_{vw}$ has exactly $i$ edges, and (b) there is no path from $v$ to $w$ with fewer than $i$ edges in $G$. The sets $N^i_G(v)$; $i=0,1,2, \ldots$ partition $V(G)$ [as $G$ is connected] and can be found via a simple Breadth-First-Search, whereas for $i=0$, note that $N^0_G(v) = \{v\}$.
3. For each edge $ww'$ with $w \in N^i_G(v)$ and $w' \in N^{i'}_G(v)$, with $i \not = i'$. Then assuming WLOG that the inequality $i > i'$ holds: Then orient edge edge $ww'$ towards $w'$.
4. We now have to orient the edges $ww'$ where $w,w'$ are in the same $N^i_G(v)$: If you insist that this orientation give an *acyclic* digraph, do the following: Give each vertex in $G$ a number from $1$ through $n$. And then for each edge $ww'$ with $w,w'$ in the same $N^i_G(v)$, assuming WLOG that $w<w'$, orient the edge $ww'$ towards $w'$. [If you do not insist that this orientation give an acyclic graph, orient each of the edges $ww'$; $w,w'$ in the same $N^i_G(v)$, any way you please.]

Now you can check that this orientation works i.e., the only sink is $v$. Indeed, let $w$ be a vertex that is not $v$. Then that $G$ is connected implies that $w$ is in $N^i_G(v)$ for some positive integer $i$, and adjacent in $G$ to some vertex $w'$ in $N^{i-1}_G(v)$. Then $ww'$ is an edge in $G$ oritented from $w$ to $w'$ and so $w$ is indeed not a sink.

Comment: Great, thank you for the alternative proposition !